# clone private git repository with HTTP in cpanel

Tags: gitlab, cpanel

I want to integrate Cpanel with GitLab instance which its repositories are private and I can't use SSH because I don't have any access to the configuration of this instance and the Cpanel server (except the ssh keys section in Cpanel itself).

In Cpanel, the git section doesn't accept HTTP URLs for private git repositories and it suggests using SSH URLs instead but I can not.

I tried to use HTTP URL with username and password in URL but it prevents me to do this. like this:
`https://USER:PASS@gitlab-instance.com/username/repository.git`

anyone can help me to access the private git repository with SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. Add an ssh key

---

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html

2. Access the repo via ssh

---

git@gitlab-instance.com:username/repository.git